# Simplest way to convert an optional String to an optional Int in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

It seems to me there ought to be a simple way to do an optional conversion from a `String` to an `Int` in Swift but I can't figure it out.

`value` is a `String?` and I need to return an `Int?`.

Basically I want to do this, but without the boilerplate:

```
return value != nil ? Int(value) : nil
```

I tried this, which seems to fit with Swift's conventions and would be nice and concise, but it doesn't recognize the syntax:

```
return Int?(value)
```

Comment: How about `Int(value ?? "")`

Comment: Yeah that's better. It's very odd to me that the initializer would not accept an optional and would just return nil if any nil were passed in. I guess Swift's type system would have a heart-attack.

Comment: I updated my answer with an Int extension that does just that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to unwrap the `String?` and use a default value `""` that you know will produce `nil`:

```
return Int(value ?? "")
```

---

**Another approach: Int initializer that takes `String?`**

From the comments:

> It's very odd to me that the initializer would not accept an optional and would just return nil if any nil were passed in.

You can create your own initializer for `Int` that does just that:

```
extension Int {
    init?(_ value: String?) {
        guard let value = value else { return nil }
        self.init(value)
    }
}
```

and now you can just do:

```
var value: String?
return Int(value)
```

Comment: I think this is the correct approach and has better readability

Comment: The `nil` coalescing approach is indeed neat and readable, but I believe it's worth pointing out that the `flatMap(_:)` approach (as compared to the `nil` coalescing one) will not call a sure-to-fail call (passing literal `""`) to the failable `Int` (by `String`) initializer if `value` is `nil`. For this reason, imho, the `flatMap(_:)` approach, or the second one above (custom initializer), is to prefer of the `nil` coalescing one.

Comment: The custom init method could be simplified slightly to `guard let value = value else { return nil }; self.init(value)`

Comment: So it can.  Thanks @MartinR!

Comment: That's actually very cool. I didn't realize you could add custom initializers in an extension!

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`flatMap()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap) method of `Optional`:

```
func foo(_ value: String?) -> Int? {
    return value.flatMap { Int($0) }
}
```

If `value == nil`  then `flatMap` returns `nil`. Otherwise it 
evaluates `Int($0)` where `$0` is the *unwrapped* value,
and returns the result (which can be `nil` if the conversion fails):

```
print(foo(nil) as Any)      // nil
print(foo("123") as Any)    // Optional(123)
print(foo("xyz") as Any)    // nil
```

Comment: Also `map` does the same.

Comment: @Sulthan: `value.map { Int($0) }` would evaluate to a nested optional, e.g. Optional(Optional(123))

Comment: @MartinR Ah yes, you are right, didn't realize the optional inside!

Answer (score 4):

With String extension you shouldn't worry about `string == nil`

```
extension String {
  func toInt() -> Int? {
    return Int(self)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var nilString: String?
print("".toInt())         // nil
print(nilString?.toInt()) // nil
print("123".toInt())      // Optional(123)
```